# How do I say "course duration" in Japanese?

Tags: syntax, phrases

I want to say something along the lines of "all engineering courses are four years long".

Should I say something like this?:
各技術コースの専攻期間は4年くらいです。

Is there a more natural way to phrase what I'm trying to say? :(
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: If each course is four years long, then there's a problem. Did you mean "all engineering disciplines"?

Comment: Yeah, I did.
How do I say that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> all engineering courses are four years long

I'm not sure what you call an "engineering course", so that's a problem for translation.  However, probably some of those would be good (although I find the last one not very natural myself).

> 工学の授業は全て四年間かかります。
>
> 工学部の課程は四年間の課程です。
>
> 工学の授業は四年間に至ります。

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Axioplase!
By engineering course, I meant an undergraduate degree course in engineering. :)

Comment: Then my second traduction is most likely to be the best one.